# Entity Framework foreign key null remained as entity entered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have 2 classes like below.

```
public class Quest
{
    public int ID{ get;set; } 

    public string Objective
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Story
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual QuestLocation Location
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
    public class QuestLocation
{
    public DateTime CreateDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double Latitude
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double Longitude
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Quest Quest
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

I created a new instance of Quest and after that I have set the location property of Quest  simply creating a new instance of QuestLocation class.

```
   Question q = new Question();
   q.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
   q.Objective = "foo";
   q.Location = new QuestLocation(){ CreateDate = DateTime.Now, Latitude = 10 , Longitude = 10 };

   And add newly created Quest into Database :
   DataContext.Quests.Add(q);
   DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

When I look at my database, Every object that i have initialized so far is created. However the foreign Key "Quest_ID" of QuestLocation remained NULL. How can I come up with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Question q = new Question();
QuestionLocation qL = new QuestLocation(){ CreateDate = DateTime.Now, Latitude = 10 , Longitude = 10 };
q.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
q.Objective = "foo";
q.Location = qL;

//And add newly created Quest into Database :
DataContext.QuestLocations.Add(qL);
DataContext.SaveChanges();

DataContext.Quests.Add(q);
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Doesn't it have a performance issue? Because in this case, you have to save changes everytime you add an object

Comment: You can try with omitting the first `SaveChanges()` method. I think, the performance issue may resolve in that case.

Comment: If I omit the first SaveChanges what is the difference between my code and your code? I mean Shouldn't it automatically set the QuestLocation object instance to quest by setting Quest_ID?

Comment: possibly you are right. But as far i remember, when i code in this scenario, i use as i give my answer. I am not sure about performance issue.

Comment: if you are using multiple savechanges then you should use transactionscoope to acheive atomicity

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a quest_id on the questlocation object.
A good practise also to have your foreign key field (quest_id) set as not null in your database.